# using $scope with controller as syntax

Tags: angularjs

***UPDATE***

here's the article where I saw the examples below: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide

after re-reading the example I realized that a specific and unique scenario was being explained, thus this question may not be fully valid. I will not delete it, however, so that if anyone has any further knowledge, they can contribute and help the community.

---

I've been reading about angular best practices and I'm convinced after reading a few articles that the best approach is to use the controller as syntax:

```
angular.module('example', [])
.controller('somectr', somectr);

somectr.$inject =['$http'];

function somectr($http) {
 var vm = this;
 this.x;
}
```

however I saw an article that shows this syntax, but it also injects a scope:

```
somectr.$inject = ['$scope', '$http'];

function somectr($scope, $http) {
 var vm = this;
 this.x;
 this.y;

 $scope.someFunc = function() {}
}
```

I thought that using the controller as syntax means no need to use a scope object. What user case would require the controller as syntax but still make use of a scope object?

Comment: Probably that code is in the middle of conversion from scope syntax to controllerAs. :) Do you see is there any reason to use it in that piece of code in the article

Comment: none. when you do  var vm = this;  you are saying vm = $scope. can you link the article?

Comment: @ajmajmajma not exactly, it means `$scope.aliasName = vm`

Comment: @ajmajmajma here's the article, search for the string `Directives and ControllerAs` https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide. I just read the section again (I had read it last night) and I see that he's doing something unique here... so my question is probably invalid

Comment: @AbdulAhmad by `someFunc` did you mean `$watch`, if so yes they are not part of controller instance they are part of scope itself for which you would need to use scope?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of injecting `$scope` even if you are using `controllerAs` is when you want to pub/sub events.

If you want to Publish some events, you would use:

```
$scope.$broadcast('eventName', value)
$scope.$emit('eventName', value)
```

For Subscribing:

```
$scope.$on('eventName', function)
```

Take a further look at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Another example would be if you are using `$scope.$watch`

There's a good article on controllerAs by ToddMotto: http://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/